# Why hasn't Team Machine told Control who was really behind Vigilance?

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

In the finale of Season 3 of *Person of Interest*, it was revealed to Team Machine and to the audience that Decima Technologies was behind Vigilance, and that they planned the bombing in the courtroom. In particular, the bombing resulted in Samaritan receiving NSA feeds and being fully activated.

Later, in Season 4 Episode 12, Team Machine had kidnapped Control and wanted to convince her how bad Samaritan is.

**Why didn't they mention the connection between Decima and Vigilance to Control?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the courtroom Control, Greer and Finch were all on trial. So naturally Control would assume that Greer had nothing to do with it. Now in season 4 even if team machine decided to tell Control about Decima's involvement in Vigilance she would not have believed her, at least not at that point, because there was no proof connecting vigilance to Decima other than Finch. All members of vigilance were killed in the explosion at the courtroom. At the very max it would serve as a warning and not as conclusive evidence that Samaritan is the bad big brother.

Furthermore in the eyes of Control it was decima that saved everyone from watching the live telecast by routing everything to a single computer. This further exonerates Greer and Decima from any blame in the eyes of the government and by extension Control too.

Answer (score 2):

Team Machine don't tell as Control will not believe it. They tried to tale more recent events just day before such a big shootout in stock exchange.
A conspiracy to breakdown America's ecomony, where ecomony does down in day time casuing mayhem. People tring suicide , mayhem. When Finch told same to Control , she didn't believed as Samiritan does clean up job perfectly.
Control denies it as long tale created to know about Sameen.

Other reason is oppurunity window, Team was expecting agents to come to recover Control. So, they started with high priority talk that is where is Sameen. 
Team Machine only understood that Control is not aware after when Finch started talking to Control. As soon as , he started talking about what Samaritan is doing, agents arived to reterive Control and all of them were busy after that.
Finch was uploading worm in encrypted phone and Fusco backing him. Other two were holding agents to give time for Finch.